# Node js + imagemagick + Error: spawn ENOENT

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Hi am trying to implement Imagemagick package using node.js

I added my following code.

```
var im = require('imagemagick');

router.post('/conversation/start', function(req, res) {

    var args = ["/public/images/team/rajini.jpg", "-crop", "120x80+30+15", "output.png"];

    im.convert(args, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }
        res.end("Image crop complete");
    });
});
```

But i getting the following error in terminal.

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
npm ERR! weird error 8
npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node"
npm WARN For further explanations, please read
/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
```

Comment: I tried to solve many way but didn't fix this issue

Comment: Did you try to read `/usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian` ??  it may help you , this may have relation to your node installation of something like this

Comment: I checked but no use for that

Comment: Is the path set correctly?

Comment: Yes. i checked twice but getting same error.

Comment: ran into the same issue, yet my code works when I run it on mac, but on not on ubuntu 14.04, both have npm 3.10.10 and node 6.10.1, @RSKMR did you manage to fix this?

Comment: @AntK - Try to give the image path from root directory.

Comment: I am running into issue on `npm install`, not on resizing. This package works like a charm on my linux machine, but not on my mac