# Imagemagick ENOENT error

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

Not only I have this issue: [Node js + imagemagick + Error: spawn ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458167/node-js-imagemagick-error-spawn-enoent)

```
console.log(appPath + '/public/avatar/tmp_' + filename);
var path = appPath + '/public/avatar/tmp_' + filename;
try {
    fs.accessSync(path, fs.F_OK);
    // Do something
    console.log('file exists!');
} catch (e) {
    // It isn't accessible
    console.log('file does NOT exist!');
}

console.log('trying...');
// crop/resize image
im.crop({
    srcPath: path,
    dstPath: 'test1.png',
    width: 60,
    height: 60
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
    console.log('here');
    if (err) {
        console.log('trololololol '+err);
        reject(err);
    }
    console.log('resized to fit within 60x60px');
    resolve();
});
```

I get the console output:

```
C:\www\instantynode\src/public/avatar/tmp_1458064183594_la5v9vcuc27hw7b9.png
file exists!
trying...
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn identify ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:178:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:344:16)
    at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:442:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:356:17)
```

Answer (score 9):

`ENOENT` means `identify` can't be found. Make sure that you have installed ImageMagick and that it is installed in a path that is found in `$PATH`.

Comment: I have same issue, I have installed the imagemagick using npm install imagemagick - not cleare what I have to do now.

Comment: can you explain exactly what we have to do after `npm install imagemagick`?

Answer (score 4):

I realize this several years late but I just ran into this issue and was able to solve it.
I thought I'd post the solution here for the next poor sap who runs into this.

identify is a legacy utility that can optionally be installed with ImageMagick.
By default, it is not installed.

[image: ImageMagick Setup]

Comment: Ahh what does this do exactly, do you know?

Comment: From the [ImageMagick documentation](https://imagemagick.org/script/identify.php): The identify program describes the format and characteristics of one or more image files. It also reports if an image is incomplete or corrupt. The information returned includes the image number, the file name, the width and height of the image, whether the image is colormapped or not, the number of colors in the image, the number of bytes in the image, the format of the image (JPEG, PNM, etc.), and finally the number of seconds it took to read and process the image.

Answer (score 2):

I was also having this error , what I did was made a copy of imagemagick.exe in the installation directory (which was c:\Program Files\ImageMagic for me) and renamed the file to identify.exe

Answer (score 1):

Just making `npm install imagemagick` does not suffice because the npm package does not contain any binaries, just node scripts which rely on the binaries.

You still have to install the binaries, in Debian/Ubuntu, you just need to do

```
sudo apt install imagemagick
```